# iOS, swift: play background music and sound effects without delay

Tags: ios, audio, swift, avfoundation, soundeffect

I am trying to create a game in iOS without using SpriteKit. 
I am stuck in getting the sound effects to play in a timely manner. I've been using the following code which I have found online and the background music plays great. However, when I use the 
"playSoundEffect" method it plays ok the first time but then starts to lag behind and becomes out of sync. I guess that happens because it initializes an AVAudioPlayer every time. 
Anyone have a good idea in how to play sound effects in a timely manner, while also playing background music? Thanks!

```
import AVFoundation

public class SKTAudio: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
public var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
public var soundEffectPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

private var mainLoopFileName:String! {

    let randomSong = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

    switch randomSong {
    //case 0: return "Test.mp3"
    //case 1: return "Test2.mp3"
    case 0: return "SneakySnitch.mp3"
    case 1: return "FasterDoesIt.mp3"
    case 2: return "MonkeysSpinningMonkeys.mp3"
    default:
        break
    }

    return "SneakySnitch.mp3"
}

public class func sharedInstance() -> SKTAudio {
    return SKTAudioInstance
}

public func playBackgroundMusic() {
    let filename = mainLoopFileName
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
        println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
        player.numberOfLoops = 0
        player.delegate = self
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } else {
        println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
    }
}

public func pauseBackgroundMusic() {
    if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
        if player.playing {
            player.pause()
        }
    }
}

public func resumeBackgroundMusic() {
    if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
        if !player.playing {
            player.play()
        }
    }
}

public func playSoundEffect(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
        println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    soundEffectPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    if let player = soundEffectPlayer {
        player.numberOfLoops = 0
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } else {
        println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
    }
}

// MARK: AVAudioPlayerDelegate
public func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool) {
    println("finished playing \(flag)")

    delay(5.0, {
        self.playBackgroundMusic()
    })
}

public func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(player: AVAudioPlayer!, error: NSError!) {
    println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could using AVPlayer to play your sound file.  Keep one player, but change its `AVPlayerItem` to a new item when you need to play a new sound.  It might be faster than recreating the player every time.

While `AVAudioPlayer`/`AVPlayer` is the simplest option, it will not give you the shortest delay or perfect synchronization when playing audio files.  You should look into Audio Queues or Audio Units within [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more accurate sound playback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are playing the second sound effect before the first one is finished. You are killing the reference to the first when you set the new `AVAudioPlayer` to your `soundEffectPlayer` variable and the first will stop playing.

If you don't mind loosing the availability of controlling the volume of the sound you could use this:

```
var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url, &mySound)
// Play
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound)
```

Otherwise you can use `AVAudioPlayer` if you add each sound that you create into an array, keeping the reference. Then you can delete it when the sound is done by implementing `AVAudioPlayer` delegate.

```
func playSound(){
    let path : NSString? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound", ofType: "wav")!
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    var error : NSError?
    let sound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    sound.delegate = self
    sound.volume = 0.5

    self.soundsEffectsArray.addObject(sound)
    sound.prepareToPlay()
    sound.play()
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool) {
    self.soundsEffectsArray.removeObject(player)
}
```